# JSON in list JS

Tags: javascript, json, list

have file_name.JSON, like

```
[{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3}]
```

How can I use "for" to get in final: 
1,2,3

```js
const file_name = [{
  "id": 1
}, {
  "id": 2
}, {
  "id": 3
}]

for (let i = 0; i <= file_name.length; i++) {
  console.log(file_name[i].id);
}
```

Or maybe another way, not use "for"

Comment: Your code works, aside for the off-by-one typo

Comment: Yes, Max, can you be a bit clearer on the result you are expecting.

Comment: You want map or reduce

Comment: You don't want to let your loop equal length. that'll give an `id of undefined` error. Are you asking about the usage of the loop or how to fetch the file?

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code  you need just to change  `i <= file_name.length` to `i < file_name.length`

```js
const file_name = [{
  "id": 1
}, {
  "id": 2
}, {
  "id": 3
}]

for (let i = 0; i < file_name.length; i++) {
  console.log(file_name[i].id);
}
```

Or for a better and clean code you can use `map`

```js
const file_name = [{
  "id": 1
}, {
  "id": 2
}, {
  "id": 3
}]

const res = file_name.map(({
  id
}) => console.log(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`

```js
const file_name = [{
  "id": 1
}, {
  "id": 2
}, {
  "id": 3
}]

let arr = file_name.map(e => e.id);
console.log(arr);

let str = file_name.map(e => e.id).join();
console.log(str);
```

Comment: At the end he states "Or maybe another way, not use "for""

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have JSON, you have a plain old Javascript array there.

```js
var file_name = [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3}];
var justNumbers = file_name.map(e => e.id);
console.log(justNumbers);
```